# Lazy Images Tableview doesn't load data

Tags: objective-c

I use Apple's example LazyTableImages and i configure fine with this example but when i embed all file to my project, my tableView doesn't show data. 
In Apple's Example `TableView` is the main view (Only one ViewController) and in my project is in the second `Viewcontrolle`r.

I changed all text have `RootViewController` to `TopPaidAppsViewController`, tableView configure same as Apple's Example.

I use `SWRevealViewController` (Sidebar) to push to `TopPaidAppsViewController`.

Here is my open project: http://chingfong.com/iClover.zip

Please help, im new on `Xcode.`

Comment: It's silly to ask but have you set delegate & datasource?

Comment: datasource delegate was my fist guess too

Comment: i did it but it not work

Comment: Your example works after I did connect the datasources. But there is no data to display.

Comment: Yes, it works but no Data to dislay, it is my problem :(

Comment: Please someone fix it for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to add the datasource delegate in the .h file of your tableview class
this should solve your problem

```
@interface TopPaidAppViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Comment: Why did you add a tableview to a viewcontroller instead of creating a tableviewcontroller in the first place? You have to create a tableView Outlet now and set its delegate.

Comment: i try to add new UITableViewController too but it is same, not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the protocol wont be enough.

In the storyboard have none of the tableviews their datasource delegate set. Only Top Paid Apps has the necessary implementation in the viewcontroller, but no data. He generates a message that he is loading if the datasource is set.

Either connect the tableviews to their controller in the storyboard or by code in the controller.[image]

[image]

Comment: i did it too and add
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
to viewDidload but it still not working

Comment: I rechecked your code. The delegate works. You gennerate a cell with the title loading and 6 more cells with no text.

Comment: Yes, Loading is the first row when data begin load and hide when data finnish load. But table doesn't load data so first row will not hide :(

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code. It seems like you are not passing data properly. You are taking data from `self.entries` array buy it is nil. If you fix that code should work for you.

Comment: I dont know what wrong in my code, and where to fix it because it works without error, only table doesn't show data

Comment: i think my TopPaidApp doesn't load LazyTableAppDelgegate so i embed @class TopPaidAppViewController to LazyTableAppDelgegate.h but it not work too :(

Comment: Code seems to messed up. I can suggest you to use cache library for lazy loading and very easy to use: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: can it load data from xml file like Apple's example? I see it load images from  _objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    @"http://assets.sbnation.com/assets/2512203/dogflops.gif",
                    @"http://www.ioncannon.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/test2.webp",
                    @"http://www.ioncannon.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/test9.webp",...
I must write image link to it, not load from xml ??

Comment: You need to parse the xml first. Then this library can load image from image url.

Comment: Do i need to find xml parser and embed to my project too? Or SDWebImage include xml parser? Thanks!!